# Hide powershell window while executing script

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I am newbie at using Powershell and scripts ..
In script file there are simple commands that I would like to run and everything is ok

```
Sub TestUDF()
MsgBox ScriptFile
End Sub

Function ScriptFile() As String
Dim wshShell        As Object
Dim wshShellExec    As Object
Dim strCommand      As String
Dim strOutput       As String

strCommand = "Powershell -File ""C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Test.ps1"""
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set wshShellExec = wshShell.Exec(strCommand)
strOutput = wshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll

ScriptFile = strOutput
End Function
```

My problem is that when running the code, the powershell window appears for two seconds. How can I hide it so as not to display this window at all?

Answer (score 3):

You would add an additional parameter on your command to call PowerShell to keep the window hidden. Adjust the `strCommand` to something like this:

```
strCommand = "Powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -File ""C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Test.ps1"""
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this parameter `-WindowStyle Hidden` and also `-nologo` but the window appears for a second ...

Comment: I would say then it is something Excel is overwriting the normal behavior. Nothing you can do about that, that I'm aware of.